# Use of typename keyword with template function parameters

Tags: c++, templates, typename

In C++, the `typename` keyword is needed so the compiler can disambiguate between nested types and nested values in templates.  However, there are certain situations where no ambiguity is possible, such as when a derived class inherits from a nested class type.

```
template <class T>
class Derived : public T::type
{ };
```

Here the `typename` keyword is not required, and is in fact not even allowed.  This makes sense, because the context removes the ambiguity.  Here, `T::type` must refer to a type, since you obviously can't inherit from a value.

I would think the same thing would hold true for function template parameters.

```
template <class T>
void foo(const T::type& v)
{

}
```

In this case, the context makes it clear that `T::type` must refer to a type, since a function parameter can't be a value.  Yet, the compiler doesn't accept this.  It wants `const typename T::type&`.  This seems inconsistent.  Why does the language allow the implicit assumption of a nested type in the context of inheritance, but *not* in the context of function parameters?  In both cases there can be no ambiguity, so why the need for `typename` in one but not the other?

Comment: This is a very interesting question.

Comment: The members of the C++ committee are human. Send in a proposed change for the next standard.

Comment: @Channel72 during my short contact with templates I've realized that there is many more inconsistent and non-orthogonal rules. I cannot say that templates were poorly designed but there is definitely room (guest room not some small box room) for improvement.

Comment: One thing worth noting is that a function argument can have a much more complicated type declaration than a base class, including pointers, references, arrays, and function types.  I don't see any way those can create an ambiguity like `T::A * b;` at block scope does, but it's at least one reason to treat function arguments different from base classes.

Comment: Your remark could apply to other unambiguous contexts such as `typedef T::type alias` or `T::type var;`. In my opinion, the best approach would be to make everything homogeneous and enforce the use of typename everywhere, without the exceptions currently existing (base-specifier and mem-initializer). Of course, this will never happen since this change would break a tremendous amount of code...

Comment: @ Luc Touraille... no, his remark doesn't apply to them...think, if you write T::type *ptr.. and suppose T::type is not actually a nested type, but a nested value.. then "T::type *ptr" would try to calculate the product of the two operands!

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, the example you give is ambiguous; I don't see how the one I gave could be. Of course, making a distinction between these two cases would probably make parsing more difficult, but as far as I know parsing C++ is already quite hard, so...

Comment: @Luc Touraille... True. Your specific example is unambiguous, but then I think, Standard requires us to use typename just for the sake of uniformity, as it also  makes programmers as well as compiler writes life easy...and so, I think, the same rationale apply to function argument, possibly!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you slightly change your declaration, you get an entire different story

```
template <class T>
void foo(T::type& v);
```

That isn't unambiguous anymore. It could declare a variable of type `void` that is initialized by a bit-wise `AND` expression. The entire declaration would be templated. Of course, this semantically is all nonsense, but it syntactically is alright.

The appearance of a single `const` syntactically makes it unambiguous, but it's too much context dependence to make this work in a compiler. It has to remember that it read a `const` or any other such thing, and when it parses the `T::type` after it will need to remember to take this name as a type. It would also further bloat the already complicated Standard beyond belief.

Let's again change your function declaration

```
template <class T>
void foo(const T::type);
```

Not even the appearance of `const` in there provides for a unambiguous parse. Should it be a function declaration with an unnamed parameter, or should it be a function declaration with an invalid parameter name that misses its type? A parameter's name is parsed by a `declarator-id`, which can also be a qualified name. So here, the `const` will belong to the type specifiers, while the `T::type` will be parsed by the compiler as the name of the parameter, in absence of a `typename`. That is totally nonsense too, [but is syntactically valid](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4594).

In the case of base-class names *name lookup itself* states that non-type names are ignored. So you get omission of `typename` for free: The name that name lookup yields to more higher level modules of the compiler either refers to a type, or name lookup will have given an error.

I have written a FAQ entry about [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/).

Comment: I don't know if I should be in awe for uncovering those cases, or truly fear for your sanity :)

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I don't think there ever was an intent to make a sharp and precise distinction between the situations where only typenames are allowed (like base class name) and situations where non-type entities are allowed as well (like expressions). I'd say that the base class name context was singled out for some other reason.

Secondly, it is not exactly correct to say that in function parameter declarations every entity is necessarily a typename. You can declare a parameter as follows

```
template <class T>
void foo(const T::type& v[T::value]);
```

Of course, the grammar in this case explicitly dictates that `type` must be a typename and `value` must be a value. However, the compiler can only figure that out *after* the syntactic analysis of the declaration, while I believe the idea of `typename` was introduced to aid the compiler in actually *starting* the proper syntactic analysis of the code, i.e. the distinction should be available *before* the syntactic analysis, as an input into the syntactic analysis. This distinction might have profound effects on the interpretation of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Would be interesting to find what is causing this.

I've been trying to read the standard in search for an answer, please note I'm am novice in this.

However I believe I've found a relevant clause.

> §14.6.2. A name used in a template
>   declaration or definition and that is
>   dependent on a template-parameter is
>   assumed not to name a type **unless the
>   applicable name lookup finds a type
>   name or the name is qualified by the
>   keyword typename**.

I guess this implies that the issue is in the difference of how name lookup works for base specifier lists and function arguments.

Base specifier name lookup:

> §10.2. During the lookup for a base
>   class name, **non-type names are ignored**
>   (3.3.10).

Which explains why **typename** is not required for base specifiers.

Still looking for function argument name lookup.

Please correct me if this is an incorrect or irrelevant assumption. In the meantime I while keep digging.

The error given by VS2010 when not qualifying the template argument in the function declaration is the following:

> 'T::type' : dependent name is not a
>   type prefix with 'typename' to
>   indicate a type.

However, I'm still unclear about the rules for dependent function argument name lookup...

Comment: A Standard requirement not to miss for this discussion: C++03 14.6p5: "The keyword `typename` is not permitted in a *base-specifier* or in a *mem-initializer*; in these contexts a *qualified-id* that depends on a *template-parameter* (14.6.2 temp.dep) is implicitly assumed to be a type name."