# Use of qualified name in function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, qualified-name

According to the C++ Standard, function parameter's name is parsed by a *declarator-id*, and a *declarator-id* can also be a qualified name. That means, the following code is perfectly  valid (if I've understood the relevant sections from the Standard correctly):

```
template<class T>
struct Sample
{
    int fun(int T::count); //T::count is qualified variable name
};
```

My question basically is, why would anyone write such code? In what situations, the use of qualified name (in function parameter-list) can be advantageous?

---

EDIT:

It seems I understood the sections incorrectly. Instead of the above code, we can probably write the following code (as per the C++ standard):

```
template<class T>
struct sample
{
  void fun(int arr[T::count]);
};
```

gcc-4.3.4 [compiles](http://www.ideone.com/qbvPo) it perfectly. But then, I'm not totally satisfied, because T::count is not a parameter anymore (I guess).

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347730/use-of-typename-keyword-with-template-function-parameters/4348172#4348172

Comment: So what's the question now? Are you still interested in finding out why anybody would want to do that?

Comment: @Martin : if you're referring to the edited part of my post, then yes, I would like to hear something from you and others, especially why would anyone use `arr[T::count]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's invalid. The syntax allows arbitrary declarators, but 8.3.5p8 says

> An identifier can optionally be
>   provided as a parameter name; if
>   present in a function definition
>   (8.4), it names a parameter (sometimes
>   called “formal argument”)

**Edit** Another quote which syntactically constraints declarators (8.3p1, [dcl.meaning]):

> Each declarator contains exactly one
>   declarator-id; it names the identifier
>   that is declared. The id-expression of
>   a declarator-id shall be a simple
>   identifier except for the declaration
>   of some special functions (12.3, 12.4,
>   13.5) and for the declaration of template specializations or partial
>   specializations (14.7). A declarator-id
>   shall not be qualified except for the
>   definition of a member function (9.3)
>   or static data member (9.4) or nested
>   class (9.7) outside of its class, the
>   definition or explicit instantiation
>   of a function, variable or class
>   member of a namespace outside of its
>   namespace, or the definition of a
>   previously declared explicit
>   specialization outside of its
>   namespace, or the declaration of a
>   friend function that is a member of
>   another class or namespace (11.4).

So in a parameter declaration, you must not use qualified names.

**Edit**: In the edited form, the function parameter type decays to an `int*`, even before a test is being made whether `T::count` actually exists and is an integer constant. If you want an example where a qualified name in such a signature would do something meaningful, consider

```
template<class T>
struct sample
{
  void fun(int S=T::count);
};
```

When `fun` gets called without parameter, the compiler needs to determine the default argument, which then fails if `T` does not have a `count` member, or that cannot be converted to `int`.

Comment: @Martin... I didn't really understand the quotation. Could you please explain that?

Comment: It says "yes, you can have a name in a parameter, but it must be an identifier (i.e. it must be unqualified).

Comment: @Martin : I don't think it says "but it must be an identifier (i.e it must be unqualified)". Also, it contradicts the grammar of *parameter-declaration-clause*.

Comment: It's explicitly forbidden by 8.3/1: "A declarator-id shall not be
qualiﬁed except for the deﬁnition of a member function (9.3) or static data member (9.4) outside of its
class, the deﬁnition or explicit instantiation of a function or variable member of a namespace outside of its
namespace, or the deﬁnition of an explicit specialization outside of its namespace, or the declaration of a
friend function that is a member of another class or namespace (11.4)."

Comment: How else would you interpret "an identifier can be provided", if they don't mean that what is optionally be provided must be an identifier? I fail to see how to contradicts: declarator->direct->declarator->declarator-id->id-expression->unqualified-id->identifier.

Comment: @Martin and @Johannes : thanks for the [updated] post and valuable comments. I'm trying to understand them. Hope it'll clear my doubts. :-)

Comment: @Martin : thanks for the update in your post. I think, it answers my question quite satisfactorily. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your code is ill formed because

> $8.3/1 : When the declarator-id is qualified, **the declaration  shall  refer  to  a  previously  declared  member  of  the  class  or namespace  to  which  the  qualifier  refers**,  and  the  member  shall  not  have  been  introduced  by  a  using-declaration  in  the  scope  of  the  class  or  namespace  nominated  by  the  nested-name-specifier  of  the declarator-id.  [Note: if the qualifier is the global ::scope resolution operator, the declarator-id refers to a name declared in the global namespace scope.  ]

P.S: I am not 100% sure. Please correct me if I am wrong. :)

---

> In what situations, the use of qualified name (in function parameter-list) can be advantageous?

Read Items 31 and 32 from Exceptional C++ by Herb Sutter. Both the items deal with Koenig lookup and the Interface principle.

Comment: thanks for the post with reference. I'll look into this & related points, and try to understand them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I understood the sections incorrectly. Instead of that code, we can probably write the following code (as per the C++ standard):

```
template<class T>
struct sample
{
  void fun(int arr[T::count]);
};
```

gcc-4.3.4 [compiles](http://www.ideone.com/qbvPo)  it perfectly. But then, I'm not totally satisfied, because `T::count` is not a *parameter* anymore (I guess).