# calling functor using function Object tr1::function<>

Tags: c++, functor, effective-c++

I try to implement Scott Mayer book code example, the example is about calling functor through function object

the header file gameCharachter.h

```
#ifndef GAMECHARACTER_H
#define GAMECHARACTER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
#include <tr1/functional>

class GameCharacter;

int defaultHealthCalc(const GameCharacter& gc);

class GameCharacter
{

public:

    typedef std::tr1::function<int (const GameCharacter&)> HealthCalcFunc;

    explicit GameCharacter(HealthCalcFunc hcf = defaultHealthCalc)

        : healthFunc(hcf)
    {
    }

    ~GameCharacter()
    {
    }

    int healthValue() const
    {
        return healthFunc(*this);
    }
private:

    HealthCalcFunc healthFunc;

};

class EyeCandyCharacter:   public GameCharacter    // another character
{

public:

    explicit EyeCandyCharacter(HealthCalcFunc hcf = defaultHealthCalc)

        : GameCharacter(hcf)
    {
        cout<<typeid(*this).name()<<"::"<<__FUNCTION__<<""<<endl;

    }                                           

};   

struct HealthCalculator                          
{
    /*explicit*/ HealthCalculator()
    {

    }

    int operator()(const GameCharacter& gc) const     // calculation function
    {
        cout<<typeid(*this).name()<<"::"<<__FUNCTION__<<""<<endl;
           return 0;
    }                                        

};

#endif // GAMECHARACTER_H
```

the main.cpp is :

```
#include "gamecharacter.h"

int main()
{
    EyeCandyCharacter ecc1(HealthCalculator());       
    ecc1.healthValue();
}
```

why function<> object refuse to call the operator() function in healthvalue()

Comment: Why are you saying it refuses to do so?

Comment: Most vexing parse. Again.

Comment: Please add the compiler you use. Some problems are compiler dependent.

Comment: My compiler is Mingw

Comment: This one eventually leads to most vexing parse too but explains your issue, after which you can click through to "most vexing parse": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903082/call-to-constructor-can-be-considered-as-function-declaration

Answer (score 1):

`EyeCandyCharacter ecc1(HealthCalculator());`

declares a function called `ecc1` that takes an argument of type "pointer to function taking no arguments and returning a `HealthCalculator`" and returns a `EyeCandyCharacter`. I assume that this isn't your intent.

Comment: I just try to implement tutorial example

Comment: ecc1  is an object of type EyeCandyCharacter and the argument it takes is an object also of type HealthCalculator

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct call , it should be called by bind

```
#include "gamecharacter.h"

int main()
{
    HealthCalculator hc;
    EyeCandyCharacter ecc1(std::tr1::bind(&HealthCalculator::operator(),hc,tr1::placeholders::_1));
    ecc1.healthValue();
}
```