# What does "int typedef" mean?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, typedef

I came across a new use of the keyword `typedef` in C++.

What does this typedef declaration mean?

```
int typedef foo;
```

Comment: Wow that's a new one. Is that portable?

Comment: Yes..It is. I have tried it.It works as @Sven says

Comment: Adding this to the things I didn't expect to learn today archive

Comment: Adding this to the things that depress me about C++ archive

Comment: Add this to the list of never do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ crazy typedef : what is the point of allowing this syntax by the Standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422816/c-crazy-typedef-what-is-the-point-of-allowing-this-syntax-by-the-standard)

Comment: Another one: `int friend main();` (inside any class definition).

Comment: @KerrekSB sometimes that has its uses: `friend int32_t ::globalFunction();` will be invalid because the `::` will take `int32_t` as a scope specifier. Writing it as `int32_t friend ::globalFunction();` makes it well-formed.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's the same as

```c
typedef int foo;
```

i.e. it defines `foo` to be the type `int`.  While the grammar allows to swap `typedef` and `int` in this case, you usually would not do this because it impairs readability.

Comment: Yes, because `typedef` is a *decl-specifier*, it can go before or after the type, just like `const`.  Never noticed that before.

Comment: `#define ALSO_KNOWN_AS typedef  /* ;-) */`

Comment: Oh. God. Is that strictly `C++` or in  `C99`?

Comment: @Lambdageek That's **awesome** (though I won't ever use it, because of the `define`thing, and because it would just confuse the reader... function declaration typedefs are confusing enough...).

Answer (score 20):

`typedef` is a decl-specifier, so it has the same syntax rules as `const` or `static`. It can be moved about like that and will mean the same thing.

Comment: No, `typedef` and *storage-class-specifier* are both kinds of *decl-specifier*, but `typedef` is not a *storage-class-specifier*.