# How to get a member typedef from an object instance

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

In MSVC2010 The following code gives:
`error C2039: 'my_type' : is not a member of ''global namespace''`

```
template<typename T>
class C
{
public:
    typedef T my_type;
};

C<int> c;

auto f = [&c]() { 
    decltype(c)::my_type v2;   // ERROR C2039
};
```

I've found a lame way to work around it but I'm wondering what the proper way is to get at the typedef when you only have an object instance.

Comment: Upgrade your compiler version or rely or workarounds, one that comes to my mind is `identity<decltype(c)>::type::my_type v2;` with `template <class T> struct identity { typedef T type; };`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I wasn't sure if it was a VC2010 problem or me just not understanding what to do.

Comment: You don't need to capture `c` either (if it's global or static).

Comment: Is `c` a `C<int>` or a `C<int>&` in the body of the lambda?  While capturing a global variable is pointless, maybe the compiler is actually doing it?  Try throwing in a decay or remove reference?

Comment: @Yakk In the real code c is not a global or static. I get the same error with
    f = [c]() {  ... }
so that would be the same as ref removal right?

Comment: @tukra then `decltype(c)` would be `C<int>&` no?  And `C<int>&::my_type` is not much sense (maybe it should work, but I could see a creaky compiler failing even if it should).  Try `typename std::remove_reference<decltype(c)>::type::my_type`?

Comment: @Yakk `decltype(c)` is `C<int>` in [gcc and clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e1aa1de91161c5a), though I don't know wich rule states so

Comment: Turns out I need identity and ref removal. remove_reference does both jobs nicely. I posted an answer with a working solution. Thanks!!!

Comment: Verified that decltype(c) is C<int>& in MSVC2010. Using type_name<T>() from the second answer at [Print variable type in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/print-variable-type-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

From a conglomerate of very helpful comments I got a working solution. Thanks everyone. remove_reference serves dual purpose as an identity object.

```
template<typename T>
class C {
public:
  typedef T my_type;
};

void g() {
  C<int> c;

  auto f = [&c]() {
    typedef remove_reference<decltype(c)>::type::my_type my_type;
    my_type v;   // Works!!
  }; 
}
```

Comment: either `remove_reference` or `identity` is redundant, pick only one

Comment: Even though MSVC accepts it as is, the standard mandates that you use `typename` here, i.e. `typedef typename remove_reference<decltype(c)>::type::my_type my_type;`.

Comment: @Oberon typename is not required

Comment: @PiotrS. I think it is, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421306/use-of-typename-keyword-with-typedef-and-new.

Comment: @Oberon I believe typename can only be used in templates.

Comment: @Oberon you *think* it is, and I *know* it's not. `remove_reference<decltype(c)>::type` is not a dependent name