# inheriting from an enable_if'd base

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-meta-programming, enable-if

I'm trying to partially specialize a trait for arrays of non-chars:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_container : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, unsigned N>
struct is_container<T[N]>
: std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, char>::value, std::true_type>::type {};
```

Visual Studio 2010 gives me a C2039 (`type` is no element of `enable_if`...). However, shouldn't SFINAE just bottom out here instead of giving a compiler error? Or does SFINAE not apply in this case?

Of course I could just separate the specializations for non-char and char:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_container : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, unsigned N>
struct is_container<T[N]> : std::true_type {};

template<unsigned N>
struct is_container<char[N]> : std::false_type {};
```

But I would really like to know why SFINAE doesn't work in this particular case.

Comment: Well, I think that `typename` is needed in front of `std::enable_if`, because of dependent type but I wouldn't put it as answer because this is just speculation!

Comment: @Arak: No. `typename` is not required in that context. While searching for base class, compiler excludes all non-types in the beginning. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347730/use-of-typename-keyword-with-template-function-parameters

Comment: Can you specify what you're trying to do, e.g. what context are you trying to instantiate `is_container` such that you expect SFINAE to kick in? On the other hand, if you need a base only conditionally, something like `std::conditional` would be more appropriate.

Comment: It might be an issue of hard error, have you tried `boost::lazy_enable_if` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the topic '3.1  Enabling template class specializations' at
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html

Edit: in case boost.org link dies...

3.1  Enabling template class specializations
Class template specializations can be enabled or disabled with enable_if. One extra template parameter needs to be added for the enabler expressions. This parameter has the default value void. For example:

```
template <class T, class Enable = void> 
class A { ... };

template <class T>
class A<T, typename enable_if<is_integral<T> >::type> { ... };

template <class T>
class A<T, typename enable_if<is_float<T> >::type> { ... };
```

Instantiating A with any integral type matches the first specialization, whereas any floating point type matches the second one. All other types match the primary template. The condition can be any compile-time boolean expression that depends on the template arguments of the class. Note that again, the second argument to enable_if is not needed; the default (void) is the correct value.

Comment: I very much doubt a link to boost.org would die, but anyways I will post a full answer.

Comment: So do I, though they reorganized their site once in the past already :)

Comment: Note that `boost::is_float` is very similar to `std::is_floating_point`.