# Why is C++ "typename" required even in cases where there is no parsing ambiguity?

Tags: c++, standards, language-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of typename keyword with template function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347730/use-of-typename-keyword-with-template-function-parameters)
>   [Use of typename keyword with typedef and new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421306/use-of-typename-keyword-with-typedef-and-new)

I understand why C++ has the `typename` keyword.  The parsing of certain token sequences, such as

```
qwert * yuiop;
asdfg(*hjkl)(zxcvb);
```

depends on whether certain identifiers (in this case, `qwert`, `asdfg` and `zxcvb`) refer to types or to values.  So in templates, sometimes it needs to be told so that it can parse the template definition.

```
template<class Qwert> void yuiop() {
    typename Qwert::asdfg * zxcvb;  // declare a pointer of type Qwert::asdfg
    Qwert::asdfg * hjkl;            // multiply Qwert::asdfg by hjkl
}
```

However, there are cases where the syntax can only accept a type, yet typename is still required.

```
template<class Qwert> void yuiop(Qwert::asdfg) {
    Qwert::asdfg hjkl;
}
```

This doesn't compile.  It seems that typical compilers assume Qwert::asdfg is a variable or constant and so throw a syntax error.  But why?

- On the first line, the parsing context guarantees that we are dealing with a function signature, not a function call, and C++ (unlike C) doesn't allow a parameter to be declared in a function signature without a type, and so what follows the open bracket *must* be a type.
- Where two identifiers are juxtaposed as on the second line, the first identifier must always denote a type.

The essence of my question is: Why doesn't the C++ standard allow type/value ambiguities to be resolved from the parsing context in cases like these?

(Note: [the nearest thing I've found online to a standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) states something to this effect near the bottom of page 301.  I don't know whether any actual standards are different in this respect.)