# 'typename' missing for MOCK_METHODx() definitions in templated mock class

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have a compiler error issue with gmock and a templated mock class that should be used as base for derived (concrete) mock classes.

The purpose is to test callback methods supported by a framework but the framework base classes are dependent on the final implementation (in short it's a CRTP pattern style framework that injects static interface declarations)-

I'm trying to sketch out what I have (please don't rely on compilable code in the 1st try):

This is the framework hooks interface definition that depends on a Context template parameter, the framework base class itself handles this as a non polymorphic call and provides a default implementation:

```
template<class Context>
class IFrameworkHooks
{
public:
    virtual void funcImpl(Context* context) = 0;
    virtual ~IFrameworkHooks() {}
};
```

Now I want to implement a mock class that implements the `IFrameWorkHooks<>` interface:

```
template<class Context, class InnerInterface>
class MyTemplateMock
: public FrameworkBaseClass<MyTemplateMock<Context,InnerInterface>,Context,InnerInterface>
, public IFrameworkHooks<Context>
{
public:
    // Compiler error here:
    MOCK_METHOD1(funcImpl, void (Context* context));
    virtual ~MyTemplateMock() {}

protected:
    MyTemplateMock()
    {
        // Compiler error here:
        ON_CALL(*this, funcImpl(_))
            .WillByDefault(Invoke(this, &MyTemplateMock<Context,InnerInterface>::funcImplCall));
    }

    void funcImplCall(Context* context)
    {
    }

};
```

I'm getting a compiler error that says:

```
error: need ‘typename’ before ‘testing::internal::Function<void(Context*)>::Result’ because ‘testing::internal::Function<void(Context*)>’ is a dependent scope
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T> class testing::Matcher’
error:   expected a type, got ‘testing::internal::Function<void(Context*)>::Argument1’
```

Is it possible to specialize the gmock Matcher used in the `ON_CALL()` macro for the template parameter somehow? Or am I missing s.th. else??

Comment: Did you try putting [typename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347730/use-of-typename-keyword-with-template-function-parameters) before `testing::internal::Function<void(Context*)>::Result`? That's what the error message says you need -- maybe it's right. (You may need to look at the preprocessor output to figure out where that is in your source code.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Hard to do, because this is buried inside the gmocks implementation of `MOCK_METHODx()` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need the template version of gmock's macros which have `_T` appended:

```
MOCK_METHOD1_T(funcImpl, void (Context* context));
```

For further info, see the section entitled "Mocking Class Templates" in [the docs](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Class_Templates).